# Find such values from a column which must be associated with all desired values from another column

Tags: sql, join

I have a lookup table with two foreign key columns. The values can be as:

| A_ID | B_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |

Now, How do I query this table to get all such ids of column `A_ID` which must be associated with a collection of desired ids of column `B_ID` i.e. From the table, If I pass the value {1,2}, I need to get {5, 9} from column `A_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming there are no duplicate entries and null values in the database.
2. Here you are providing the list which is [1,2], so in advance, you can calculate the length of the list, here it is 2.
3. Now let's say have a list `list1` and length of it is `n` then the query will look something like this

```
    SELECT temp.A_ID
    from (SELECT * FROM table where B_ID in list1) as temp 
    group by temp.A_ID 
    having count(*) >= n;
```